# XML DOM remove element tags and preserve child nodes in place within parent element with text nodes

Tags: xml, element, strip-tags, xmldom

Is there a way to target this here

I am wanting to strip out the ctag element but preserve its child nodes IN PLACE so that we get
Is there a way to target this here

and am trying to do this using XML DOM rather than regular expressions.  However I can remove the
element but am not able to place the child nodes correctly

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: javascript, using nodejs XML DOM package to manipulate xml